# How do I add icons in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, icons

I was running Ubuntu 18.04 and just converted to Xubuntu.  Is there a way to add icons to the desktop?  I would like a few to launch programs.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the desktop and choose `Create Launcher` from the context-menu to create custom launchers.

You can also choose any program from the application-menu with a right-click and select `Add to Desktop` from the context-menu.

Answer (score 0):

**Creating Desktop shortcut using terminal**

You could do it in the next way:

```
ln -s /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop /home/user/Desktop/
```

But it shows an alert: `Untrusted application launcher`

Also, you could create it by creating app.desktop file on your desktop with the next content:

```
vim.tiny ~/Desktop/firefox.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Firefox
Comment=Browser
Exec=firefox
Icon=firefox
Path=/home/user/.firefox
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false

chmod +x ~/Desktop/firefox.desktop
```